# Table variable in sp_executesql parameter list

Tags: t-sql, ssms, dynamic-sql

I'm having trouble sending a table variable into a sp_executesql parameter list.

my Table Variable:

```
declare @MemberCoverageIds table (CoverageId ID_t)

insert into @MemberCoverageIds( CoverageId) select MemberCoverageId from MemberCoverages where MemberNumber = @FulfillmentEntityIdentifier
```

My where clause using the table variable:

```
@WhereClause = @WhereClause + 'and F.FulfillmentEntityId in (select CoverageId from @MemberCoverageIds) '
```

it is part of my FinalSQL variable which has the rest of the statement:

```
select @FinalSQL = @InsertClause + @SelectClause + @JoinClause + @WhereClause
```

and then I have the execute:

```
exec sp_executesql @FinalSQL,
                    N'  @FulfillmentEntityIdentifier    RefNumber_t,
                        @MemberCoverageIds              ReadOnly,
                        @EntityId                       Id_t,
                        @FulfillmentEntityType          Code_t,
                        @FulfillmentDocumentType        Code_t,
                        @FulfillmentMethod              Code_t',
                        @FulfillmentEntityIdentifier    = @FulfillmentEntityIdentifier,
                        @MemberCoverageIds              = @MemberCoverageIds,
                        @EntityId                       = @EntityId,
                        @FulfillmentEntityType          = @FulfillmentEntityType,
                        @FulfillmentDocumentType        = @FulfillmentDocumentType,
                        @FulfillmentMethod              = @FulfillmentMethod
```

I then get an unexpected error from that execution. I know it is the @MemberCoverages table variable because it worked before I added it. My question is what would be the proper syntax for sending the table variable in the parameter list? Do I have to declare it in the Parameter list?

Comment: Variables/parameters only exist in the scope they are declared in. They will not exist in the dynamic statement, as that is a separate scope. You would have to `CREATE` a table type with the definition of your table variable, and then declare that as a parameter for your call to `sp_executesql`.

Comment: Why is this statement dynamic in the first place though?

Comment: Also, do you *really* have a datatype called `ReadOnly` in your database? Though `READONLY` is not a (future) reserved keyword, it is a keyword, and it therefore seems like a poor choice of a name for a user defined data type. In fact, the data types of all your parameters for `sp_executesql` are user defined data types, which seems really odd.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It's dynamic because it can change with user input, a table variable must be passed as read only in a tsql procedure, they are all user defined because that's just how my company does it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a named type that your table variable will use:

```
create type dbo.myTableType as table (id int)
```

Then you can use it as a typed argument to sp_executesql:

```
declare @m dbo.myTableType;
insert @m values (1), (2)

exec sp_executesql 
    N'select 99 where 1 in (select id from @m)', 
    N'@m dbo.myTableType readonly', 
    @m
```

If you don't want to create a new type, you can use a #temp table:

```
declare @t table(id int);
insert @t values (1), (2);
select * into #t from @t;

exec sp_executesql N'select 99 where 1 in (select id from #t)';
```