# Select from @localvariable with user-defined table type

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have here a query that select from a local variable. It is working fine with my other stored procedures that didn't have array parameter and when I applied it to this stored procedure it is now not working.

Here is my script below.

```
AS 

DECLARE @serverpath varchar(255)
DECLARE @query varchar(max)

BEGIN

SET @serverpath = (SELECT [path] from [param] where [platform] = 'PLMS')

SET @query='
SELECT
''PLMS'' as PLATFORM,
''PLMS''+ ''0''+ordh_sysrefno as ZINDEX,
ad_sapcode AS "SAP ADVERTISER CODE",
ad_advcde AS "PLMS ADVERTISER CODE",
ad_advnme AS "ADVERTISER NAME",
ag_sapcode AS "SAP AGENCY CODE",
ag_agencde AS "PLMS AGENCY CODE",
ag_agennme AS "AGENCY NAME",
ordh_docno AS "TO NUMBER",
ordh_createdate AS "TO CREATE DATE",
ordh_conttp AS "CONTRACT TYPE",
tt_desc AS "TELECAST TYPE",
'''' AS "PACKAGE TYPE",
'''' AS "REVENUE TYPE",
sapcode as "SAP PROGRAM CODE",
pg_prgcode as "PLMS PROGRAM CODE",
pg_prgname as "PROGRAM",
ordd_teledte AS "TELECAST DATE",
ordd_agencost AS "INTERNAL COST",
ordd_billcost AS "BILLING COST",
''PHP'' AS CURRENCY,
'''' AS PRODUCTION,
spd_cpno as "CP NUMBER",
cph_cpdte as "CP DATE",
cph_prndte as "CP PRINT DATE",
CASE ordh_conttp
WHEN ''C''
       THEN spd_invno
WHEN ''X''

       THEN spd_exinvno
WHEN ''P''
       THEN spd_pbinvno
ELSE '''' END AS "INVOICE NUMBER",
spd_stat as "STATUS"
from
' + @serverpath +'.ord_hdr INNER JOIN
' + @serverpath +'.ord_dtl ON (ordh_sysrefno = ordd_sysrefno) INNER JOIN
' + @serverpath +'.spot_dtl ON (ordd_sysrefno = spd_sysrefno and ordd_dtlno = spd_dtlno ) INNER JOIN
' + @serverpath +'.program ON (pg_prgcode = ordd_prgcode ) INNER JOIN
' + @serverpath +'.advertiser ON (ad_advcde = ordh_advcde) INNER JOIN
' + @serverpath +'.agency ON (ag_agencde = ordh_agencde)  INNER JOIN
' + @serverpath +'.cp_hdr  ON (ordh_sysrefno = cph_refno and spd_cpno = cph_cpno) INNER JOIN              
' + @serverpath +'.cp_dtl  ON (cph_cpno = cpd_cpno and cpd_dtlno = ordd_dtlno and cpd_spotno = spd_spotno) FULL OUTER JOIN

' + @serverpath +'.telecast_type ON (ordd_teletp = tt_code) left outer join
PLMSSAP.PLMSSAPSU.programs_season on (platform = ''PLMS'' and pg_prgcode = PLMScode and
cpd_teledte BETWEEN date_start AND date_end)
WHERE
cpd_cpno in (Select LTRIM(RTRIM(StringValue)) FROM @StringAsArray)
'

EXEC (@query)
END
```

and this is my c# script

```
 public static DataTable SelectFromLocal(string stdproc, string name, DataTable cps)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.TableName = name;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BMSSAP"].ConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(stdproc, con))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    var param = new SqlParameter();
                    param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
                    param.Value = cps;
                    param.TypeName = "StringArray";
                    param.ParameterName = "@StringAsArray";
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

                    cmd.CommandTimeout = 60 * 60 * 60;
                    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                            sda.Fill(dt);
                    }
                }
            }
            return dt;
        }
```

and I got this error every time I run my application

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException`: 'Must declare the table variable "@StringAsArray"'.

Comment: You appear to have decapitated the stored procedure! The signature is missing from your question :)

Comment: You're executing dynamic SQL. The execution of the dynamic SQL has its own scope. The variables that are used inside the dynamic SQL must be declared. Variables created outside that scope are not automatically available to the dynamic SQL. If you want to pass a value into the dynamic sql from the outer scope, you can do so using sp_executesql. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63003749/7165279)

Comment: @allmhuran what do you mean by I am missing the signature from my question?

Comment: @allmhuran can you give me a sample base on my scenario? Thank you. and Im sorry Im just a newbie.

Comment: I mean your `create procedure` line is missing :D. Give me a minute to write up an answer for you with more details

Comment: The scope comment is your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is one of scope. Wikipedia has a *very* detailed definition of scope [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)). If you want a quick summary, [this](https://www.educative.io/answers/what-is-scope) isn't terrible.

You have dynamic-SQL in your code. By that I mean you are building a SQL statement as a string, and then executing the string using `exec()`.

When you do that, everything inside the `exec()` is running in its own scope. It  can't see any variables that were declared outside of the string you created.

Here's a simple example

```sql
declare @var varchar(20) = 'hello';  -- this is in the outer scope
exec
(
   'select @var;'  -- this will run in its own scope
);
```

What will happen when I run that? Do I get the result "hello"? No, the variable `@var` was only declared in the outer scope. In the inner scope it has not been declared. So I get an error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@var".

But just declaring it doesn't help, I want to pass the variable from the outer scope to the inner scope. This won't do what I want:

```sql
declare @var varchar(20) = 'hello'
exec('declare @var varchar(20); select @var');
```

That will run without causing an error, but the result will be `null`. The `@var` inside the string is not associated with the `@var` in the outer scope.

What I need to do is bind the outer `@var` to the inner one. You can do this with the `sp_executesql` procedure. THe following code will do what I want. It will output "hello":

```sql
declare @var varchar(20) = 'hello';

exec sp_executesql 
   N'select @var',      -- the first argument is the statement I want to run
   N'@var varchar(20)', -- the second argument is a comma separated string of parameter definitions
   @var;                -- the subsequent arguments map the variables from the outer scope to the parameter definitions
```

I am not going to write out the entire construct for your case, because your dynamic SQL statement is very long. But you have an identical situation. You have a variable which lives in the outer scope as a table valued parameter. You want to send that variable into the scope of the dynamic SQL.

```sql
create type dbo.MyStringArray as table (MyString varchar(20));
go

create or alter procedure MyProcedure (@MyTvp dbo.MyStringArray readonly) as
begin
   declare @dynamicSQL nvarchar(max) = 'select MyString from @MyTvp';
   exec sp_executesql
      @dynamicSQL,
      N'@MyTvp dbo.MyStringArray readonly',
      @MyTvp;
end;
go

-- I can now call this using:
declare @t dbo.MyStringArray;
insert @t values ('hello');
exec myProcedure @t;
```

**NOTE** that you must declare the variable which will hold your dynamic SQL as `NVARCHAR`, not `VARCHAR`, in order to use `sp_executesql`. Same with the parameter definitions. If you prefix a literal string with the letter N, it is an nvarchar (as in my example).